# Latest Google PHP client library has no working autoloader

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

The latest [Google PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) has no working autoloader. It has one autoloader, which doesn't actually load anything, and just throws the following exception:

> google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to
>   src/Google/autoload.php in 1.1.3. This redirect will be removed in
>   1.2. Please adjust your code to use the new location.

Just to confirm that autoload.php doesn't actually do anything, here's the code inside:

```
if (!defined('E_USER_DEPRECATED')) {
  define('E_USER_DEPRECATED', E_USER_WARNING);
}

$error = "google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to src/Google/autoload.php in 1.1.3. This ";
$error .= "redirect will be removed in 1.2. Please adjust your code to use the new location.";
trigger_error($error, E_USER_DEPRECATED);
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

I've taken a look in `src/Google/` and I don't see a *single* file named autoload.php. I've also checked  all the folders, and there is absolutely nothing.

I've also tried putting `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/google-api/src/Google/src');` in my code too, which the docs says to do [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation). This didn't work either.

How can I use the client library?

Comment: Did you try adjusting your code to the new location?

Comment: Just to be clear there is a difference between an API and a client library your question originally stated API, you are having issues with the PHP client library.  They are two very different things.  I have corrected your question to correctly reflect the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to copy the Google directly from the client library,  then you will be able to do the following.

```
 require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
```

Example directory structure:

```
 index.php
 Google/
```

If you choose to copy everything you can but you need to map to the path correctly.

```
src/Google/autoload.php
```

Is not the correct path to your autoload.php file. it may be an issue of what directly you have placed things in because [src/Google/autoload.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/autoload.php) does exist in the project

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was due to a problem when I downloaded the files, so I didn't end up getting most of them (including the autoloader in `src/Google/`)

I've re-downloaded the files, and it's fine now.